# RecyclerView количество строк

Tags: java, android, view, recyclerview

Можно ли указать количество строк в `RecyclerView`, когда в горизонтальном режиме прокрутки, к примеру в `GridLayout` указывается `android:columnCount="4"`?  существует ли что-то такое для `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, это делается в коде. В момент реализации `LayoutManager`, там есть 3 дефолтных менеджера и в 2 из них, нужно указывать эти параметры

Comment: спасибо, получилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решил проблему с использованием `GridLayoutManager`

```
rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
rv.setLayoutManager(glm);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
```